# OpenCV 2.4.11 Installation Error - No rule to make target `opencv_test_java_properties', needed by `modules/java/test/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_java'

Tags: java, opencv, installation

I am trying to install OpenCV 2.4.11 on RHEL 6 (64 bit) machine. I have downloaded the tar file from github. I am getting following error -

```
[ 76%] Built target opencv_test_java_properties
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `opencv_test_java_properties', needed by `modules/java/test/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_java'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [modules/java/test/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_java.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Please note that my cmake command executes successfully. FFMPEG and JAVA tests return 'YES'. But, when I try to use make command, it gives me above error message. I can see these folders created on path /opencv-2.4.11/release/modules/java/test/CMakeFiles/. Still it is not able to find it.

I get the same error message for installation of other opencv versions too. My cmake version is 2.6-patch 4.

Please help me to solve this error as I am not able to complete this since a long time.